# Using PHP to call python script

Tags: php, python, exec, html

I have the following PHP code that I want to use to call a python script (ring.py)

```
  <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; 
    $output = exec('python ring.py');
  ?>
```

The program ring.py creates 2 files. When I run the PHP script from command line:

```
php index.php
```

then the php script correctly runs the python script and 2 files are created as desired.

However when someone accesses the PHP page through a web browser, it doesn't seem to run the python script and no files are created. How can I fix this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: check for errors using `if(!$output)` and print the error

Comment: how do I print the error exactly?

Comment: die(exec_error) will do

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Python script on the server is executable

```
chmod +x ring.py
```

and make sure it's either in the same directory as the PHP script or use the full path.

Comment: yes I tried that already and it works when I run the php script from command line so that's not the issue. Its just it doesn't work when someone accesses the php script through the web browser. Any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219982/getting-php-to-run-a-python-script here's a similar question that might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `chmod 0777 ring.py`, because just doing `+x` will affect just your user. Normally, PHP is executed by another user (usually, `anonym`), that probably is not in the same group as yours.