# Execute python script with output from php

Tags: php, python

Is there any special permission or setting in order to execute a python script that create a new file or image? 
This is my code:

```
<?
function py(){
    exec( 'python my_script.py');
    echo "ok";
}

py();
?>
```

And this is my python script (an example):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

f = open('out.txt', 'w')
print >> f, 'thats all'
f.close()
```

Running php i get "ok" message but no file is created. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: PHP should be executed by user `www-user`. So the Python script would be stared from the same user. Does `www-user` has the desired permissions to execute the Python script and access file-system for file-creation?

Comment: How can i check that? @albert

Comment: I have never done this since I am not a PHP user so everything I am talking about is just mind-based. First you should find out which user is the owner of the folder and the script you want to access. If this is not `www-user` you could either change the user to `www-user` or pass the desired user name to the `exec` command as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913403/running-command-line-application-from-php-as-specific-user)

Comment: run you php script by root permission. sudo script.php

Comment: @MehrdadDadvand i can't, php file is executed via ajax when a button is clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting PHP to run a Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219982/getting-php-to-run-a-python-script)

Comment: @albert not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the right permissions to file and folders did the trick.

[image]

On Mac OS: Alt + Click on "+", then search for _www and add World Wide Web Server to users giving read and write permission. Same for the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `shell_exec()` not `exec()` if you want to be able to capture the output:

[Refernce: PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)

Comment: This is more of a way to debug, so it should be a comment, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I don't need to capture output, i want python script to execute and create files. In fact using shell_exec() has no effect